# Sequence contains no elements in MVC3 Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, sequence

So a drop down is used to select the users name, then click 'view' and it will display all the holidays this user has previously booked.

From here the user can click 'create new' which will bring them to a create new page.
Instead of having to re-select their name from another drop down i carried across the currentuserID and replaced the second drop down with the users ID.

Everything was working fine with 2 separate drop downs, the user could book holidays etc...
However now (after I changed the second drop down to hold the ID value) I am getting an error from my listHoliday Method in my controller:

**Error: InvalidOperationException was unhandled by the user code. Sequence contains no elements.**

```
var dbPerson1 = (from p in db.People
                             where p.Id == PersonId
                             select p).Single();
```

---

Could anyone advise what to do?

Comment: This means that your `from...select` did not return any elements, i.e. you have no person with an `Id` of `PersonId`.

Comment: `Sequence contains no elements` means the Linq Query is returning no results. Output PersonId and see what the value is (I'm guessing null)

Comment: Also, you might find LINQs lambda syntax a bit more readable, e.g. `db.People.Single(p => p.Id == PersonId)`.

Comment: Try `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Single` and check if `dbPerson1` is `null`.  Your predicate is preventing any results from being returned.  Have you checked the value of `PersonId`?  Perhaps you're losing the value from your View.

Comment: @RichardEv Thanks everyone for the replies. PersonId is returning null, so i changed it to '14' an id for the user, and it worked fine, Changed single ro singleOrdeFault and now the next line is thorwing an error saying dpPerson1 is null in....if (dbPerson1.HolidaysRemaining > 0)

Comment: @roryok thanks for the reply please see above msg

Comment: @DavidHoerster thanks for the reply please see above msg

Comment: Iv just tried added   if (dbPerson1 == null)
            {
                return Content("No Such Person with ID" + PersonId + "found");
            } and dbPerson is returning null...how can I go about troubleshootin this can someone please advise?

Comment: What is `PersonId` when you run the application without hard-coding it to 14?  I think your problem is before you get to the LINQ statement -- `PersonId` isn't getting set.

Comment: @DavidHoerster You are correct I used:if (dbPerson1 != null && dbPerson1.HolidaysRemaining > 0) and this by passed the problem but said they user had no holidays (when i know they did)...used a breakpoint and persinId is null, personId ismt being brought over, any idea on how I can resolve this?

Comment: How are you setting `PersonId`?  If it's coming from your View and you're getting it from the controller action method as an argument, make sure the control NAME in your View is also `PersonId`.  If you're doing something else in order to get `PersonId` set, then you should update your question and that will help in resolving your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means the linq query you're doing returns no results, to .Single() throws an exception.

try

```
var dbPerson1 = (from p in db.People
                         where p.Id == PersonId
                         select p).FirstOrDefault(); // or use SingleOrDefault() if People are unique

if (dbPerson1==null) 
{
    throw new HolidayAllocationException("Person not found");
}
else
{
    // person found
    if (dbPerson.HolidaysRemaining > 0) 
    {
        AllocateHoliday(); // or whatever you need to do
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new NoHolidayLeftException(); 
    }
 }
```

`dbPerson1` will then be null if the query doesn't return anything.

hope that helps

Comment: You could also use `SingleOrDefault` if you expect a single item to be returned at most.  An exception will be thrown if more than one is returned by the predicate.

Comment: @sambomartin thanks for the reply. PersonId is returning null, so i changed it to '14' an id for the user, and it worked fine, Changed single ro singleOrdeFault and now the next line is thorwing an error saying dpPerson1 is null in....if (dbPerson1.HolidaysRemaining > 0) –

Comment: you want to check for `if (dbPerson1 != null && dbPerson1.HolidaysRemaining > 0)`

Comment: @sambomartin thanks for the reply, that allowed the user to book a holiday but it kept saying they had no holidays left (when i know they did) used a breakpoint and personId is being reutrned as a null, can you advise how i can troubleshoot this? thank you

Comment: `if (dbPerson1==null) { /* person not even found */ return false; } else if (dbPerson1.HolidaysRemaining >0 ) { /* ok to do the action, they have holiday */ } else { /* no holiday left!! */ }`

Comment: @sambomartin thank you for taking the time to help with that much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

[When you get theLINQ Error "Sequence contains no elements", this is usually because you are using the First() or Single() command rather than FirstOrDefault() and SingleOrDefault().](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2009/12/17/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements.aspx)